# need help formatting a date parameter in Oracle BI Publisher RTF template

Tags: oracle, date-format, bi-publisher

I'm not talking about using the parameter in the data template - I'm all set there.  I need to know how to change the format of a parameter once it hits my RTF template.

I have

```
<?param@begin: p_Date?>
<? $p_Date?>
```

This gets my parameter from the report request page onto my report.  However, I can't seem to alter the format.  I'm sure I just need to understand how to access it, but I'm not that familiar with BI Publisher.  I know I can alter the format on the request screen, and that flows through, but I need to alter it on the end result.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it. You can use the [format_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22254/extend_func.htm) function; the documentation is a little sparse.  My syntax looks like this:

```
<?xdoxslt:format_date($p_Date, 'MMM yyyy','MM-dd-yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)?>
```

The first parameter is the target format, the second is the input mask.  The second can be overridden to use a [specific l18n style](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2463664).